# Should concrete class follow the type hint of its interface?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface

In this code sample, the interface doesn't seem to care whether the implementing method `foo()` checks for an `array` type parameter even if it explicitly type-hinted `array` only.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

interface MyInterface
{
    public function foo(array $foo);
}


class Bar implements MyInterface
{
    public function foo($foo)
    {
        return $foo;
    }
}


echo (new Bar)->foo('test'); // runs just fine as string
```

I would expect at least a fatal, incompatible interface error; but there's none.

My questions are:

1. Is this an expected behavior?
2. Should the interface not have type hints at all because it's not respected anyway?

Comment: FWIW, I used PHP 7.3 in a recent project that also used type-hints in interfaces and I got fatal errors when my classes didn't use the exact same type-hint as the interface's methods, but I was using very strict error_reporting settings.

Comment: @Dai if I type-hint the concrete class method with `string`, it errors but if it's not type-hinted it allows it like the example. I'm on 7.2. Does putting no type hint errors in PHP 7.3?  Because if it does, then that fixes it.

Comment: @Dai On PHP 7.2+ parameter type widening allows you to omit the parameter type, but you can't declare an incompatible parameter type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

This is expected behaviour since 7.2, and interfaces type hints are enforced to an extent; but implementing classes may *omit* the interface's type declaration (but can't declare a parameter type different from the one declared in the interface).

#### Long answer:

This was a change introduced on PHP 7.2.

If you try this in PHP where `PHP_VERSION_ID >= 7 && PHP_VERSION_ID < 7.2` you get:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Bar::foo($foo) must be compatible with MyInterface::foo(array $foo)

But on `PHP_VERSION_ID >= 7.2` it "works". The explanation for [the changes is documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php), and says:

> #### Parameter type widening
>
> Parameter types from overridden methods and from interface
>   implementations may now be omitted. This is still in compliance with
>   LSP, since parameters types are contravariant.
>
> ```
> interface A {
>     public function Test(array $input); }
>
> class B implements A {
>     public function Test($input){} // type omitted for $input }
> ```

You can omit the parameter type, but you **can't** declare an incompatible type.

E.g. if in your example you tried:

```
public function foo(string $foo)
{
    return $foo;
}
```

It would fail all around.

A couple of links for further reading regarding this change:

- [The PR](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/parameter-no-type-variance)
- [A post where the PR is explained and defended](https://blog.kelunik.com/2018/01/23/parameter-type-widening.html)
- [An example of developers taking advantage of the new functionality](https://github.com/http-interop/http-middleware/issues/65).

Comment: I see but is that really a good idea? I'm not sure if I'm happy about this change. Maybe I don't get it yet but this totally breaks the concept of interfaces for me.

Comment: I've added a couple of links to the answer that may convince you otherwise. I found it intriguing the first time I encountered it, but I came around to agree with the change myself.